# Action button in Notification Payload Issue

Tags: android, notifications

Action button should be visible in the notification payload , When the app is in background.

I am able to see the action button only in the data payload.

```
{
    "to":"FCM TOCKEN",

    "data":
    {
        "message":"MSG",
        "message_title": "custom"
    },
    "notification": {
       "body": "MSG",
       "message_title": "Placing order",
       "content_available": true,
       "priority": "high"
   }

}
```

Action button is not getting visible when the app is in background.
It is getting visible only when the app is in foreground

Comment: Is there any solution you found??
I also facing same issues.